# Is Oauth2 a suitable choice for our needs?

Tags: java, security, authentication, playframework, oauth-2.0

### 1 - Current situation

- We've got a REST API (coded with the Play framework 2.5 in Java) and four front-end interacting with it (two web apps: a back office and our site coded with React, and two mobile apps: Android and iOS).
- Everything is working correctly, but without user management.

### 2 - What we want to do

- We would like to add user management with two roles: user (can sign up and log in to our site and our mobile apps) and admin (can do everything a user can do plus can log in to the back office). In other terms, administrators can use all web services whereas users can only use some of them.
- Firstly, users have to be able to sign up with email and password.
- In a second time (this is not part of our MVP), we would like to give the opportunity to register using a Google or a Facebook account.

### 3 - Technical choice

- After reading a lot, we think that an authentication whose authorization step is taken care of by Oauth2 is a suitable choice.
- But, during our research, we found articles that have made us hesitate, with sentences like theses ones:

> "You should only use OAuth if you actually need it. If you are
>   building a service where you need to use a user’s private data that is
>   stored on another system — use OAuth. If not — you might want to
>   rethink your approach!"
>
> "To be clear, OAuth 2.0 at the hand of a developer with deep
>   understanding of web security will likely result is a secure
>   implementation. However, at the hands of most developers — as has been
>   the experience from the past two years — 2.0 is likely to produce
>   insecure implementations."

- We're not going to implement Google or Facebook authentication right away and don't have a "deep understanding of web security", so we question the relevance of choosing Oauth2.

### 4 - Implementation

- We've understood the way Oauth2 works and are not afraid by the implementation of the client side, it seems straightforward (and many projects exist to facilitate its implementation).
- On the contrary, for the server side, we will have to create an authorization server and it scares us a bit because we don't know how to do. Implement the whole by ourselves seems to be a fairly substantial and difficult job (and we didn't find any example using Play Java), we're scared to make a mistake that would create a security hole and don't want to reinvent the wheel. We've found some tools like Apache Oltu or Spring Security (that I've used in another project) but we're not sure if they're suitable for what we want to do.

### 5 - Questions

- **Is Oauth2 really a suitable choice for our needs?**
- **If we choose Oauth2, what should we do about implementation? Trying to do it by ourselves? Using a tool like Apache Oltu or Spring Security?**

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*